# how to read specific tag values from a web xml document

Tags: c#, xml, web

I'm using C#. I have a web page that is in XML format (though you do not see the format in the actual URL).

Example:

..../api/rest/v1/items/ZPA

Part of the page (the part I care about looks something like this):

```
<Identifiers>
<Identifier name="v" value="zzzz"/>
<Identifier name="id" value="29382bb53cc73af32153276fe0a6cd6c"/>
<Identifier name="qn" value="wyz-zz1"/>
<Identifier name="index" value="1111"/>
<Identifier name="item" value="ZPA"/>
</Identifiers>
```

I need to read this from the web, and grab the "id" value. How would I go about doing this? The id value in this case would be "zzzz." I need to grab it and store it in a variable.

Comment: please remove the broken link..it doesn't work..

Comment: the link isn't supposed to work, it's just an example. i modified it to remove the hyperlink.

Comment: Do you want ALL of the values?  Or do you only want the "value" of the value attribute where the name attribute is specific?

Comment: does the web page you are trying to get at have a .XML extension..? please clarify if so I will post an example on how to get at the "id" value

Comment: @maldevane, no, i just want the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(<url here>);
string targetValue =
  (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifier")
  .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "v")
  .Attribute("value");
```

This assumes that you want to be able to target one of the Identifier nodes by name, and that you are sure that there will be an element WITH that name.  If that is not true, then the .Single call will throw an Exception if that node is not found.

If you needed to use credentials and wanted to use a WebClient, then you could use the following:
(Note, I have done no exception handling, checking for stream availability, or otherwise disposed/closed the streams, just an example of how to get it to "work")

```
string uri = "> url here! <";
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wc.OpenRead(uri));
string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
string targetValue =
  (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifier")
  .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "v")
  .Attribute("value");
```

Comment: im trying to give this a try but I need to specify credentials to use "rootElement"... how would I go about doing this? I do know that an instance of WebClient, I can specify the credentials...but what about your example above?

Comment: Read the contents in separately as noted above -- then once you have the content of the xml, you can use the static .Parse method to get it into the XElement (LINQ to XML) object.

Comment: almost there. I'm getting an error at the end saying: "Sequence contains no matching element" ... this is what i have: string targetValue = (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifiers")
                .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "id")
                .Attribute("value");

Comment: (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifiers") -- should be (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifier")

Comment: tried that and it didnt work. so i replaced "single" with "SingleOrDefault" and I got a different error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Have you examined the xml content you're getting back? And ensured that there is ONE node of type "Identifier" with a name attribute of value "id"?  I ran this example using the xml you provided over a test webserver and using .Single with "Identifier" worked fine.  The reason you need rootElement.Elements("Identifier") is because (using "Identifiers") you'd be grabbing the wrong set of nodes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15079/discussion-between-maldevane-and-user1336632)

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I don't know the exact circumstances of how you get the xml itself, but once you have it, you can do the following to parse it.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlstring = "<get the xml string somehow>";
        xDoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
        //or
        xDoc.Load("filepath");
        XmlNode xnode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Identifier[@name='v']");
        string value = xnode.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("http://Myserver.tld/api/rest/v1/items/ZPA");

            var idElement = document.Descendants("Identifiers").Elements("Identifier").Where(element => element.Attribute("name").Value == "id").FirstOrDefault();
            string idValue = idElement != null ? idElement.Attribute("value").Value : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you say you need to use a WebClient for credentials (as per your other reply):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // Set credentials...   
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(client.DownloadString("<YOUR_URL>"));
    // Select the Identifier node with a 'name' attribute having an 'id' value
    var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Identifier[@name='id']");
    if (node != null && node.Attributes["value"] != null)
    {
        // Pick out the 'value' attribute's value
        var val = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
        // ...
    }
}
```

I find 'traditional' .NET XML easier to comprehend than LINQ to XML, but YMMV.

Comment: for some reason this is returning NULL

Comment: @user1336632 - I've tested this with the example XML you gave and it worked for me. Do you know at what point the null appears? Is it at the selection of the first Identifier node or somewhere else?

Comment: @user1336632 - is there a namespace associated with the document? This would need to be taken into consideration, too.